# Passing varying number of function arguments into a function using a for loop Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, dictionary, arguments

I am trying to pass in varying number of function arguments into a function. Specifically, I am trying create a meshgrid using numpy.meshgrid, with variable number of inputs: i.e. n-dimensional grid that is determined by user input.

I have a collection of arrays to produce the grid within a dictionary. The keys being the indices, and the items of the dictionaries being an array containing the points that I wish to make the grid from.

Right now, I feel that I can do it with a for loop somehow like this:

`dict= {'v1':np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'v2':np.array([5,6,7,8,9])}
grid = np.array(np.meshgrid(for keys in dict.keys: dict[keys]))`

In other words, the number of arguments I wish to pass on to numpy.meshgrid are dependent on the number of keys in my dictionary, and I want to pass on the corresponding list I have stored as items in my dictionary. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Can you add more of your code?

Comment: A function can accept a variable number of *positional* arguments this way: `def f(*positional_args):`, or a variable number of *keyword* arguments this way: `def g(**keyword_args):`. The convention in python is to abbreviate positional args and keyword args to `*args` and `**kwargs`, respectively. Is this what you're looking for? Unpack your dictionary to the function call like this: `function(**my_dict)`.

Comment: As dictionaries are unordered you'd probably want to do something like `np.meshgrid(*(dict[k] for k in sorted(dict)))`. -- Btw. it is generally discouraged to shadow the names of builtins (`dict` in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want

```
import numpy as np

dict= {'v1':np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'v2':np.array([5,6,7,8,9])}

def give_me_grid(d):
  return np.array(np.meshgrid(*(v for _, v in sorted(d.items()))))

print(give_me_grid(dict))
```

Comment: The order of `d.values()` is undefined. To make your `give_me_grid` behave predictably you have to address this. Btw. if you care about style [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says: "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier. Yes: `def f(x): return 2*x` No: `f = lambda x: 2*x`"

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you for your valuable comment. I have learnt something. It has been updated.

Comment: @Ken if you think it is helpful, please consider accepting this answer